# How can I deactivate the checkbox after submit?

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

Let's say I have in one form an input text and a checkbox and the action of the form is a page php. If 'x' condition of the input text were true and the checkbox were checked before submit, how could I deactivate the value of the checkbox in the page action of the form?

Comment: have you tried anything already?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23003232/disabling-checkboxes

Comment: is not working with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with JavaScript by assigning an event listener to the form submit event:

```
var ele = document.getElementById("myForm");
if(ele.addEventListener){
    ele.addEventListener("submit", callback, false);  //Most browsers
}else if(ele.attachEvent){
    ele.attachEvent('onsubmit', callback);            //IE...
}
```

Then, you can disable the checkbox in the `callback` function:

```
function callback(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();

    var myCondition = true; // Customize to your needs

    if (myCondition)
    {
        document.getElementById("myCheckBox").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2wx7a/1/).

Comment: if i have to work with php variables can I do this ?

Comment: What do you mean? You can't work with PHP variables on the client side.